# Reordering divs on responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am aware of the col-md/xs/sm/lg, as well as push/pull capabilities of Bootstrap.

I have the following issue:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    ..content here..
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
      ..content that when on responsive needs to be rendered first..
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       ..rest of the content..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Online version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJijn**

I want the the col-md-12 content to be pulled first when we're on small screen sizes, WITOUT the "..rest of the content.." also being pulled first.

Requirements:

1. dont' use position absolute
2. use a bootstrap way to do this
3. worst case scenario: use minimal extra css
4. if you suggest an HTML re-ordering make sure it will work

I am attaching two sketches the before/after how I want it to order to make things easier to understand.[image: desktop-before] After: [image: responsive-after]

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing an online example. It would be great if you could provide a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJijn

Comment: I think its not possible. push/pull logic is working fine inside the row only

Comment: so they have to be in the same row to make push pull work..

Comment: I might have something that would work. I cannot test on small devices (hence i can't get the col-xs-12 to apply instead of col-md-6) using this fiddle, but. Change the "50%" of the col-md-6 to "100%" (to simulate device switch from md to xs sizes being applied) and it should ruffly yield the results you sketched above.
http://jsfiddle.net/pcd3jjz9/1/

Comment: Marvin either I didn't understand what you suggested or you misunderstood what I want. Did you say I have to apply 100% instead of 50% to the col-md-6 div? I don't have a md-6 div in my example.

Comment: Ehh, no don't modify col-md-6. It's bootstrap's. you're sketchs shows 2 columns (hence col-md-6 * 2) for widescreens. col-xs-12 kicks in on small screens. Since i couldn't test on read media queries, i misuse the col-md-6 for in the fiddle only to test.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics are a little hard to decipher, but I think I understand what you're going for...

**DEMO http://www.bootply.com/rwwiuNalrr**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning">Header</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-right bg-danger">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 bg-success">Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 pull-right bg-info">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Some notes:

- When you say "goes responsive" I assume you mean "on mobile", in which case, it's good to start your HTML with that in mind, since BS3 is "mobile first". Doesn't always work, but usually, and this time it did.
- Your graphics and markup suggest you want column1 and column3 to be within the same div. From a layout POV that's not necessary and makes it difficult to separate them on mobile. Here I have connected them visually without embedding one in the other.
- You don't normally have to declare col-xs-12 since it's the default, but because we've messed with the layout by using pull-right, we have to be explicit.

Comment: Sorry for removing the right answer, I think it will help you if you see the actual page http://www.gplus.gr/ . I'll look into your answer in detail and comment later today. Thank you